# Dart/Flutter async function return -Instance of '_Future<dynamic>'

Tags: flutter, function, dart, asynchronous, return

### I am using async Function on Dart/Flutter. I want to return a string value from function.

```
Map dataLoginEmployee = {
  'email': employee.getEmail(),
  'password': employee.getPassword(),
};

String bodyLoginEmployee = json.encode(dataLoginEmployee);

postDataLoginEmployee() async {
      final response = await http.post(
        Uri.parse(url),
        headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
        body: bodyLoginEmployee,
      );
    
      return response.body;
    }
```

return response.body 's return:
Instance of '_Future'

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wxYPe.png)

> I am try a lot of method but they are didn't work.

- I try use getter setter.
- I try Future< String >, void, static, dynamic.

Please help me in a any way, Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a Future and how do I use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63017280/what-is-a-future-and-how-do-i-use-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `await` before calling `postDataLoginEmployee()`.